# Any Android libraries to resize images in place?

Tags: android, kotlin, image-resizing, android-library, android-image

Are there any Android libraries to resize images and save it in place? I'm using Jetpack Compose and Kotlin in my project. My app has a feature for taking photos and choosing an image from the gallery. And I need to resize the captured or selected image and create their thumbnails. I looked into Picasso, and Glide, etc. But, it seems like they only resize the image in memory for display.

Answer (score 1):

HI You can use Glide for resize,
but again you can use it to save as image too

for eg use this to store in bitmap,

```
  Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/quwoe.jpg")
                .asBitmap()
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                        saveImage(resource);
                    }
                });

//code to save the image 

    private void saveImage(Bitmap resource) {

        String savedImagePath = null;
        String imageFileName =  "image" + ".jpg";


        final File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                "/Pics");

        boolean success = true;
        if(!storageDir.exists()){
            success = storageDir.mkdirs();
        }

        if(success){
            File imageFile = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
            savedImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
            try {
                OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                resource.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
                fOut.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Add the image to the system gallery
            galleryAddPic(savedImagePath);
            Toast.makeText(this, "IMAGE SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
// Add the image to the system gallery
    private void galleryAddPic(String imagePath) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(imagePath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
```

1. Resize with glide
2. save with Glide

Comment: The compiler throws an error that `.asBitmap()` is an unresolved reference.

Comment: you must add the asBitmap() right After with() and it will work just like old times.